# Calculated SSAS Member based on multiple dimension attributes

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

I'm attempting to create a new Calculated Measure that is based on 2 different attributes.  I can query the data directly to see that the values are there, but when I create the Calculated Member, it always returns null.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Absorption]
 AS sum
(

    Filter([Expense].MEMBERS, [Expense].[Amount Category] = "OS"
           AND ([Expense].[Account Number] >= 51000 
           AND [Expense].[Account Number] < 52000))
    ,

    [Measures].[Amount - Expense]
), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Expense';
```

Ultimately, I need to repeat this same pattern many times.  A particular accounting "type" (Absorption, Selling & Marketing, Adminstrative, R&D, etc.) is based on a combination of the Category and a range of Account Numbers.

I've tried several combinations of Sum, Aggregate, Filter, IIF, etc. with no luck, the value is always null.

However, if I don't use Filter and just create a Tuple with 2 values, it does give me the data I'd expect, like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Absorption]
 AS sum
(

    {( [Expense].[Amount Category].&[OS], [Expense].[Account Number].&[51400]  )}
    ,

    [Measures].[Amount - Expense]
), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Expense';
```

But, I need to specify multiple account numbers, not just one.

Comment: Do you have a typo?   How can an AccountNumber be > 51000 AND < 5200?

Comment: Is `Account Number` a measure? If it is a hierarchy, `[Expense].[Account Number] >= 51000` is interpreted by SSAS as `([Expense].[Account Number].[All], [Measures].CurrentMember) >= 51000`!

Comment: @FrankPl - I didn't explain that well.  I have a Fact table called Expense.  The only Measure I've defined so far is the SUM of the ExpenseAmount column.  [Amount Category] and [Account Number] I am treating as Dimension attributes.  Account Number is not a heirarchy, it is just a list of 5 digit account numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should only use the `FILTER` function when you need to filter your fact table based on the value of some measure (for instance, all Sales Orders where Sales Amount > 10.000). It is not intended to filter members based on dimension properties (although it could probably work, but the performance would likely suffer).

If you want to filter by members of one or more dimension attributes, use tuples and sets to express the filtering:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Absorption]
AS 
    Sum( 
       {[Expense].[Account Number].&[51000]:[Expense].[Account Number].&[52000].lag(1)} *
       [Expense].[Amount Category].&[OS],
       [Measures].[Amount - Expense]
    ), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Expense';
```

Here, I've used the range operator `:` to construct a set consisting of all `[Account Number]` members greater than or equal to 51000 and less than 52000. I then cross-join `*` this set with the relevant `[Amount Category]` attribute, to get the relevant set of members that I want to sum my measure over.

Note that this only works if you actually have a member with the account number 51000 and 52000 in your Expense dimension (see comments).

An entirely different approach, would be to perform this logic in your ETL process. For example you could have a table of account-number ranges that map to a particular accounting type (Absorption, Selling & Marketing, etc.). You could then add a new attribute to your Expense-dimension, holding the accounting type for each account, and populate it using dynamic SQL and the aforementioned mapping table.

Comment: this is potentially wrong. If 51999 does not exist in the cube then it is evaluated as `null` hence your statement becomes `[Expense].[Account Number].&[51000]:null` which is very different. A date dimension is a very safe place to use the range operator as membership is generally complete ...

Comment: @whytheq: No, an error will be raised if the member is not found. You are thinking about the StrToMember function, which evaluates to null unless the constrained flag is specified.

Comment: thanks for editing your answer. Please test your suggestion as no error is raised. I will add to my answer.

Comment: @whytheq turns out you're right. I could have sworn that referencing a non-existing member in a tuple/set expression would raise an error, but I must be thinking about something else. Anyhow, my edited answer should make it clear that this only works when you're actually referring to known members.

Comment: lol - I encountered this issue with `:` last week - certainly makes it potentially dangerous when used with anything other than Dates. Also if the users hierarchy is not in the correct order then it will not fail but will return strange answers (if you're feeling generous you could even up my answer :) ) ....p.s. nice defense using `lag`

Comment: Indeed, I discovered the same thing myself trying this out.  I had to modify the range to use members that actually exist in the range.  Your suggestion to create another table to map account types is what I'm going to go with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't go near cube scripts but do you not need to create some context via the `currentmember` function and also return some values for correct evaluation against the inequality operators (e.g.`>`) via the use of say the `membervalue` function ?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Absorption]
 AS sum
(
    [Expense].[Amount Category].&[OS]
    *
    Filter(
       [Expense].[Account Number].MEMBERS,
       [Expense].[Account Number].currentmember.membervalue >= 51000 
       AND 
       [Expense].[Account Number].currentmember.membervalue < 52000
    )
    ,

    [Measures].[Amount - Expense]
), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Expense';
```

---

EDIT

Dan has used the range operator `:`. Please make sure your hierarchy is ordered correctly and that the members you use with this operator actually exist. If they do not exist then they will be evaluated as `null`:

Against the `AdvWks` cube:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,{
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[4]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2009]&[2]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns the following:

[image]

If the left hand member does not exist in the cube then it is evaluated as `null` and therefore open ended on that side:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,{
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[4]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[1066]&[2] //<<year 1066 obviously not in our cube
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I don't know enough about the syntax of mdx yet.  I did try your idea and still the same thing, all null.